# Install Next with older version of React in it

Tags: reactjs, next.js, material-ui, yarnpkg

I'm a beginner and I'm starting a new project with Next.js, but I need to install the 17.0.2 version of React (or any that is below 18) since Material UI does not work very well with the latest version of React.

I tried a lot of commands and searches to find a way to start a new project with a certain version of React or give it a downgrade correctly.

Currently I'm using Yarn.

Comment: You can downgrade `react` and `react-dom` in your project to v17.0.2, just run `yarn add react@17.0.2 react-dom@17.0.2`.

Comment: could this bug my project? Because some features work with this currently version, downgrading it could maybe make some features doesn't recognize/work with React.
That's why I'm trying to find a way to create a project already with the old version of React

Comment: you can use --legacy-peer-deps flag but its dangerous, you should review every dependency conflict to make sure nothing breaks in your project